# How to split number into digit strings?

Tags: java

I am new to java programming, I tried a sample code to get input a two digit number and print the wording of that number.

```
public class ReadNumberInWord {

    public Integer number;

    public ReadNumberInWord() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number to read out : ");

        try {
            number = userInput.nextInt();
            readNumber();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
            new ReadNumberInWord();
        }
    }

    public void readNumber() {
        System.out.println("Entered number is : " + number);
        int numSize = number.toString().length();
        System.out.println("number size is : " + numSize);

        switch (numSize) {
            case 1:
                sizeOne();
                break;
            case 2:
                sizeTwo();
                break;
            case 3:
                sizeThree();
                break;
            case 4:
                sizeFour();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Enter number of four digit or less ");
                new ReadNumberInWord();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sizeFour() {
        System.out.println("Number in words : " + numberCheck(number.toString()));
    }

    private void sizeThree() {
        String[] sizeThree = number.toString().split("");
        System.out.println(sizeThree[0]);
        System.out.println(sizeThree[1]);
        System.out.println(sizeThree[2]);

        for (int i = 0; i <= sizeThree.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(sizeThree[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Number in words : " + numberCheck(number.toString()));
    }

    private void sizeTwo() {
        String[] sizeTwo = number.toString().split("");
        //System.out.println(sizeTwo[0]);
        //System.out.println(sizeTwo[1]);
        String wordsString1 = "";
        ArrayList<String> wordsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= sizeTwo.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(sizeTwo[i]);
            String words = numberCheck(sizeTwo[i]);
            wordsArray.add(words);
        }

        for (String w : wordsArray) {
            wordsString1 += w + "\t";
        }
        System.out.println("Number in words : " + wordsString1);
    }

    private void sizeOne() {
        System.out.println("Number in words : " + numberCheck(number.toString()));
    }

    public String numberCheck(String numb) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numb);
        switch (num) {
            case 0:
                return "zero";
            case 1:
                return "one";
            case 2:
                return "two";
            case 3:
                return "three";
            case 4:
                return "four";
            case 5:
                return "five";
            case 6:
                return "six";
            case 7:
                return "seven";
            case 8:
                return "eight";
            case 9:
                return "nine";
            case 10:
                return "ten";
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReadNumberInWord();
    }
}
```

In the above code, if I enter two digit number as 78, it should print seven eight. But, that is not working here. Instead I got exception. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Post the exception...

Comment: That's a serious code duplication you have there..

Comment: And btw there's no digit "10"...

Comment: @MarounMaroun It's reasonable given presumed knowledge level during learning here.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well...damn. I'm going to step out.

Comment: Remove `catch (Exception e)` and post the stacktrace of the exception. First it's a bad idea to catch Exception, and it's even worse if you're not printing the stacktrace of the Exception, because you don't know what's happening. If you want to control a specific error, catch the appropriate exception, not all exceptions.

Comment: WHat @m0skit0 means is adding `e.printStackTrace()` (and posting it)

Comment: @user16547 It's better to remove the try/catch because it's a bad catch. The exception will be printed anyway.

Comment: @m0skit0 It's not sufficient to say "exception handling is bad, remove the catch block". The OP is clearly attempting to handle an error and recover. It would be more useful to explain a better approach to error handling there.

Comment: @JasonC You're right, but that's not related to the question, and posting that as a comment makes no sense (due to the length). If I knew what error he's getting, I would answer properly. And +1 to your answer btw.

Comment: If you want to treat the entered number as a String, why don't you read it as a String in the first place? e.g. `userInput.nextLine()`. You could use `Integer.parseInt()` or a regular expression to ensure that the user has only entered numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Stack traces are *very* useful pieces of information when debugging, and if you are encountering an unexpected exception but disregarding the stack trace, you are ignoring this information. Had you printed the stack trace for your exception, you would have seen this:

```
Enter the number to read out : 
78
Entered number is : 78
number size is : 2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at ReadNumberInWord.numberCheck(ReadNumberInWord.java:74)
    at ReadNumberInWord.sizeTwo(ReadNumberInWord.java:58)
    at ReadNumberInWord.readNumber(ReadNumberInWord.java:26)
    at ReadNumberInWord.<init>(ReadNumberInWord.java:13)
    at ReadNumberInWord.main(ReadNumberInWord.java:94)
```

This shows clearly that `Integer.parseInt()`, via `numberCheck()`, is being called with an empty string `""` for input, which is not a valid integer and causes `Integer.parseInt()` to throw the exception you are seeing.

Now you need to figure out *why* that is happening. You know that the string passed to `parseInt()` comes directly from `numberCheck()`s parameter, so that means `numberCheck()` is being passed an empty string. Since you know that input comes from the `sizeTwo` array in `sizeTwo()`, a good start would be to print the contents of that array there:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sizeTwo));
```

Doing this, you would see:

```
[ , 7, 8 ]
```

That first empty element is a hint. Using split in this way is not quite right, technically the input string starts with an "empty" string and you end up getting that back (e.g. splitting `":7:8"` on `:`). You'll have to either make `numberCheck()` ignore empty strings, or find another way to split the string into digits. The former is a band-aid over the root cause of the issue (remember: it wasn't your actual intention to include any empty strings in the digit list), so we'll focus on the latter.

One option is to convert the number to a `String` (skip the `String[]` thing) and then a `char` array, e.g.:

```
char[] digits = number.toString().toCharArray();
```

Then you can work on `char` instead of `String`. Another option is to use `substring()` in your loop, e.g.:

```
String numberstr = number.toString();

for (int n = 0; n < numberstr.length(); ++ n) {
   String digit = number.substring(n, 1);
   ...
}
```

Of course, having this string middle-man isn't really necessary, and you could just do it with arithmetic:

```
for (int n = (int)Math.log10(number); n >= 0; -- n) {
    int digit = (number / (int)Math.pow(10, n)) % 10;
    System.out.println(digit);
}
```

Or in reverse but without relying on floating point calculations:

```
int temp = number;

while (temp) {
    digit = temp % 10;
    temp /= 10;
    System.out.println(digit);
}
```

Your code can be cleaned up and greatly simplified in a lot of other ways (e.g. as Richard Miskin hinted at in a comment, do you really need a parsed `int` at all?), but I think the above covers the root of your immediate issue.

---

As for the error handling itself, I recommend just using `Scanner.next()` to read a string, then you can use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse it and if you see a `NumberFormatException`, ask again. This would be an appropriate use of an exception, and the use of `next()` rather than `nextInt()` pulls the token off the stream even if it is an invalid int (letting you continue asking for input). For example:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number to read out : ");

while (true) {
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(userInput.next());
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException x) {     
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer");
    }
};
```

Note a few key concepts here:

- The narrowest exception possible is caught (i.e. `NumberFormatException`, not `Exception`). Makes sense because: NumberFormatException is the *only* problem we're attempting to handle.
- Exception handlers should generally attempt to recover; otherwise there's no sense in handling them. In this case, our recovery attempt is to notify the user that something went wrong and ask for new valid input.

Your current implementation sets up a recursive stack and has a few other issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with:

```
String[] sizeTwo=number.toString().split("");
```

when number is "78", it produces the array ["", "7", "8"], instead of ["7","8"].
You should split the string into digits differently (or ignore the first token which is always an empty string).

split(..) accepts a regular expression that specifies what patterns to be considered as token separators. In your case, I found the following regex useful:

```
String[] sizeTwo=number.toString().split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\d)");
```

It requires the separator to be an empty string, preceded and followed by a digit (using a feature called positive lookbehind and positive lookahead)

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little odd that you're reading characters from the terminal as an `Integer` and then having to jump through hoops to convert it to an array of character for further processing. The logic can be simplified by reading in a `String`, validating that the `String` meets your requirement and then processing each character from the `String`.

There are a few other changes I'd make:

1. There is no reason to treat each length as a special case,
2. You can loop rather than calling the constructor again in the case of errors,
3. `number` doesn't need to be a member variable, you can just pass it as a parameter to each method call,
4. You don't need to convert the individual elements of `String` back to integers for the switch statement if you use `toCharArray()`.

Here's an example that works with `String` rather than `Integer`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadNumberInWord {

    public ReadNumberInWord() {
        final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number to read out : ");
        boolean success = false;
        // Keep looping until the correct input is supplied.
        while (!success) {
            final String number = userInput.nextLine();
            if (validNumber(number)) {
                readNumber(number);
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param number
     *            the String to check.
     * @return <code>true</code> if and only if number is less than 5 characters
     *         long and can be parsed as an integer.
     */
    private boolean validNumber(final String number) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(number);
            if (number.length() <= 4) {
                returnValue = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter number of four digit or less ");
            }
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * When supplied a String that represents an integer this method writes out
     * each digit as a word to stdout.
     * 
     * @param number
     *            a String that represents an integer
     */
    public void readNumber(final String number) {
        System.out.println("Entered number is : " + number);
        final int numSize = number.length();
        System.out.println("number size is : " + numSize);
        final char[] chars = number.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(numberCheck(chars[i]));
            if (i < chars.length - 1) {
                System.out.print('\t');
            } else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param num
     *            a character that represents one of the numbers 0-9
     * @return the word representing the supplied number e.g. zero, one etc
     */
    public String numberCheck(final char num) {
        switch (num) {
        case '0':
            return "zero";
        case '1':
            return "one";
        case '2':
            return "two";
        case '3':
            return "three";
        case '4':
            return "four";
        case '5':
            return "five";
        case '6':
            return "six";
        case '7':
            return "seven";
        case '8':
            return "eight";
        case '9':
            return "nine";
        default:
            return "unknown";
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new ReadNumberInWord();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for addressing other ways to simplify (and **documenting**!). I suggest using character constants ('0', '1', '2') rather than ASCII codes for readability. :)

Comment: Good call - I've switched to the character constants.

Answer (score 0):

easilly try this
digit.ToString("#,0 ")
it will divid and seperate the digit 3 by 3 from the right side.